# SFTP - Allow user to upload to www only

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

Ubuntu Server 12.04

I need to allow the user `offlineuser` to upload files to the `var/www/mysite/web/` directory only. This directory acts as a site root as well as an upload location (legacy setup).

Within my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

With the following commented out , they can upload anywhere. As soon as I uncomment this, they cannot connect at all.

```
AllowUsers offlineuser ubuntu

Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/mysite/web/%u       
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        PasswordAuthentication no
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

offlineuser is a member of sftponly group

This was taken from : [Chroot SFTP connection](https://survivalguides.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/chroot-sftp-connection/) and [OpenSSH SFTP chroot() with ChrootDirectory](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590)

**UPDATE1**

```
:pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user offlineuser by (uid=0)

: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/mysite/"

: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user offlineuser
```

So, this is pretty clear , but do I really have to chown the dir to offlineuser? Will that not cause issues if www-data wants to write to it (which is likely?)

Comment: What's the output of `scp -v` and the contents of the server log?

Comment: ah! good thought. Log output added.

Comment: You probably don't need www-data to write to /var/www/mysite, but to some path underneath it, right?

Comment: technically , the dir that offline user needs to write to is /var/www/mysite/www

Answer (score 2):

From the [sshd_config manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

It seems that all parent directories must be only writeable as root, even for SFTP. If this is not possible I would suggest moving the directory elsewhere (e.g. `/home/web/offlineuser`), and then symlinking/bind-mounting it into place.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the chroot directory to be

```
ChrootDirectory /var/www/mysite/web/
```

and then give the user a home directory of */testuser* in */etc/passwd* then you can have */var/www/mysite/web/* correctly owned by root and */var/www/mysite/web/testuser* can be owned and writeable by testuser.

Comment: That's part of the issue, /var/www/mysite/web/ has to be writable by offlineuser. /var/www/mysite/web/offlineuser won't work for this setup due to the amount of legacy stuff going on.

Comment: Just move the chroot up a level then and change the home directory for offline user accordingly.